# python convert string list into a dataframe list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of string dataframes that I want to turn into a list of dataframes.

```
temp_df = {}
temp_df['mdf1'] = df1[df1['b']<=0.4]
temp_df['mdf2'] = df1[df1['a']<=0.58]

def get_list(temp_df):
    return [*temp_df]

temp_list = get_list(temp_df)

temp_list
```

Doing this I get the stringed list:

```
output: ['mdf1', 'mdf2']
```

However, I also want a list of the two dataframes itself.
For the desirable output of:

```
output: [mdf1, mdf2]
```

I've tried this but it doesn't give me what I want:

```
temp_df.keys()
```

```
output: dict_keys(['mdf1', 'mdf2'])
```

Comment: You have a dictionary with string keys and dataframe values...

Comment: j1 unfortunately that gives me the values. Not the key itself.

Comment: BeRT2me yes. If I do something like temp_df['mdf1'] I get the values. However, I want to just be able to do mdf1 and then get the values. And then I want that specifically in a list with the other dataframes.

Comment: import pandas as pd
temp_df = {}
temp_df['mdf1'] = pd.DataFrame(data = ['1st DF', 1, 1, 10, 100])
temp_df['mdf2'] = pd.DataFrame(data = ['2nd DF', 2, 2, 20, 200])
mdf1 = temp_df['mdf1']
mdf2 = temp_df['mdf2']
[mdf1, mdf2]

Comment: That works but I have a couple dozen dataframes in which I have to put in a list. Where I have to convert the keys (containing dataframes) in the dictionary into variables. Then put those variables into a list. 

Is there a way to go about that?

Comment: Just for curiosity, what will you do with the list of variables after obtaining it?

Answer (score 0):

Check with `locals` then

```
variables = locals()
variables["mdf1"] = df1[df1['b']<=0.4]
variables["mdf2"] = df1[df1['a']<=0.58]
```